# How to use MAX/MIN functions in a calculated column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I typed a code that calculated area available per person in different countries(Surface area/Population). I wanted to know the minimum and maximum values out of this column along with the corresponding country names, however, it seems to return wrong country name i.e. Aruba in both cases, but the reported per person area is correct.

I've tried to apply max/min functions on the calculated column.

The code I typed :

```
select Name ,
       SurfaceArea,
       Population,
       Max(SurfaceArea/Population) AS per_person_area
from country;
```

The expected result should be :

> Minimum - Macao(per person area of 0.000038)
>   Maximum - Greenland(per person area of 38.6801)

The result I am getting is :

> Minimum - Aruba(Per person area - 0.00038)
>   Maximum - Aruba(Per person area - 38.6801)

Please highlight where I am making a mistake ?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and we need to also have `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` otherwises we can't help you figuring out what wrong..

Comment: ..  also `select Name ,
       SurfaceArea,
       Population,
       Max(SurfaceArea/Population) AS per_person_area`   does not make lots off sense from the SQL point of view, in fact it should give you a error read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) as it is explained..

Answer (score 1):

Your GROUP BY is incorrect. You could write the query like this:

```
SELECT Name
     , SurfaceArea
     , Population
     , SurfaceArea / Population AS PerPersonArea
FROM country
WHERE SurfaceArea / Population IN (
    SELECT MIN(SurfaceArea / Population) FROM country UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(SurfaceArea / Population) FROM country
)
ORDER BY PerPersonArea
```

An alternate method of writing the same query:

```
SELECT country.Name
     , country.SurfaceArea
     , country.Population
     , country.SurfaceArea / country.Population AS PerPersonArea
     , CASE WHEN country.SurfaceArea / country.Population = minratio THEN 'Minimum'
            WHEN country.SurfaceArea / country.Population = maxratio THEN 'Maximum' END AS MatchType
FROM country
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(SurfaceArea / Population) AS minratio
         , MAX(SurfaceArea / Population) AS maxratio
    FROM country
) AS x ON country.SurfaceArea / country.Population IN (minratio, maxratio)
```